# " Trigger has an Unresolved reference to User" but just in Visual Studio database project

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2015, database-project

I´m creating a database trigger in a **database project** in Visual Studio and that´s where I get the following error (and just in the trAudit_Transactions.sql file but not when I run it on the db server)

> Trigger: [MYDB].[trAudit_Transactions] **has an unresolved reference to User** [MYDB_Audit].

and  my trigger looks like this

```
CREATE TRIGGER [trAudit_Transactions] ON [MYDB].[TRANSACTION_WAIT]
WITH EXECUTE AS 'MYDB_Audit'  -- the error comes from here
FOR INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE 
AS
...
```

And since I can´t publish/build the solution (because of the error) I just comment out line nr 2 and create the script, uncomment the erroneous part and it runs just fine on the server.

**Why/what is this?** And just in Visual Studio? Everything works just fine when I change the published script and run it against the db.

The rest of the create is here

```
CREATE LOGIN   [MYDB_Audit]     WITH PASSWORD = N'xxx' CHECK_POLICY = OFF;
CREATE USER    [MYDB_Audit]     FOR LOGIN     [MYDB_Audit];
CREATE ROLE    [db_mydb_audit]  AUTHORIZATION [dbo];
ALTER  ROLE    [db_mydb_audit]  ADD MEMBER    [MYDB_Audit];
GRANT CONNECT                   TO            [MYDB_Audit];
```

I have tried everything I can think of and searched everywhere without any luck.

What is going on here? What am I missing?

Comment: this seems similar:http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/107556/unresolved-reference-to-user-after-importing-as-a-vs-db-project

Comment: I think it depends of how you logging in the DB from VS and MSSQL server tools. Not everyone has access to check users roles and privileges.  I think this link will help you [link to msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/execute-as-clause-transact-sql)

Comment: Thanks @Seyran I´ll take a look.